# ¿Sidebar en angular?

Tags: angular

Soy bastante nuevo en angular y estoy construyendo un sidebar, pero tengo problemas a la hora de hacerlo. Tengo un *btn* en mi *navbar* y quiero que al pulsarlo se desplace el sidebar de izquierda a derecha y cuando se vuelva a pulsar regresarlo a su posición  anterior. Sé como hacerlo en *jquery* o *javascript*, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo en angular.
[image: Aqui les muestro como es la vista, la div en negro vendria siendo el menu lateral]

```
<nav class="navbar  navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="sidebarbtn()">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <p class="navbar-brand  my-auto mx-auto" style="color: rgba(224, 33, 19, 0.829);">Inventory</p>
     
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar" >
        
    </div>
</div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})

export class NavbarComponent{

    

    constructor(){

    }




    sidebarbtn(){
       //Como accedo al sidebar??//
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes utlizar un servicio para comunicarte con el sidebar, este se encargara de almacenar su estado.

Answer (score 0):

sugiero que utilices angular material e instalas un Schematics (navigation) te crea rápidamente un sidenav

```
ng generate @angular/material:navigation <component-name>
```

https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics

Espero te ayude!